# Why are my jquery script animating at different times?

Tags: jquery

My jquery snippets are animating at different times. I want all three to load once scrolled upon, but the first graph is loading before everything else. Here is my code:

```
<div class="container">
            <div class="row">
              <div class="row-centered">
                <div class="col-lg-3 col-centered">
                    <h1>Increase Sales Time</h1>
                    <div id="myStathalf1" data-startdegree="45" data-dimension="250" data-text="33%" data-info="Sales Time" data-width="30" data-fontsize="38" data-percent="33" data-fgcolor="#FF6961" data-bgcolor="#eee" data-type="half" data-fill="#ddd"></div>
                </div>
                <div class="col-lg-3 col-centered">
                  <h1>Increase Clients</h1>
                    <div id="myStathalf2" data-startdegree="45" data-dimension="250" data-text="50%" data-info="New Clients" data-width="30" data-fontsize="38" data-percent="50" data-fgcolor="#FF6961" data-bgcolor="#eee" data-type="half" data-fill="#ddd"></div>
                </div>
                <div class="col-lg-3 col-centered">
                  <h1>Decrease Operation Costs</h1>
                    <div id="myStathalf3" data-startdegree="45" data-dimension="250" data-text="50%" data-info="Sales Operations" data-width="30" data-fontsize="38" data-percent="50" data-fgcolor="#FF6961" data-bgcolor="#eee" data-type="half" data-fill="#ddd"></div>
                </div>
                    <script>
                    $(function(){
                        var isGraph1Viewed=false;

                        $(window).scroll(function() {
                           if(isScrolledIntoView($('#myStathalf1')) && isGraph1Viewed==false){$('#myStathalf1').circliful();isGraph1Viewed=true;}
                        });

                        function isScrolledIntoView(elem){
                            var docViewTop = $(window).scrollTop();
                            var docViewBottom = docViewTop + $(window).height() - 10; //the 20 is the amount pixels from the bottom to consider the element in view
                            var elemTop = $(elem).offset().top;
                            var elemBottom = elemTop + $(elem).height();
                            return ((elemBottom < docViewBottom) && (elemTop > docViewTop));
                        }
                    });
                    $(function(){
                        var isGraph2Viewed=false;

                        $(window).scroll(function() {
                           if(isScrolledIntoView($('#myStathalf2')) && isGraph2Viewed==false){$('#myStathalf2').circliful();isGraph2Viewed=true;}
                        });

                        function isScrolledIntoView(elem){
                            var docViewTop = $(window).scrollTop();
                            var docViewBottom = docViewTop + $(window).height() - 10; //the 20 is the amount pixels from the bottom to consider the element in view
                            var elemTop = $(elem).offset().top;
                            var elemBottom = elemTop + $(elem).height();
                            return ((elemBottom < docViewBottom) && (elemTop > docViewTop));
                        }
                    });
                    $(function(){
                        var isGraph3Viewed=false;

                        $(window).scroll(function() {
                           if(isScrolledIntoView($('#myStathalf3')) && isGraph3Viewed==false){$('#myStathalf3').circliful();isGraph3Viewed=true;}
                        });

                        function isScrolledIntoView(elem){
                            var docViewTop = $(window).scrollTop();
                            var docViewBottom = docViewTop + $(window).height() - 10; //the 20 is the amount pixels from the bottom to consider the element in view
                            var elemTop = $(elem).offset().top;
                            var elemBottom = elemTop + $(elem).height();
                            return ((elemBottom < docViewBottom) && (elemTop > docViewTop));
                        }
                    });

                    </script>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
```

I typically need to scroll down a bit more for graph myStathalf2 or myStathalf3 to load.

Comment: You have x3  $(window).scroll(function()'s why not do everything you want within 1 function call

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I believe that each of the 3 functions bound to the scroll event are getting fired one after the other one, I suggest moving the code to a single one:

```
$(function () {
    var isGraph1Viewed = false, isGraph2Viewed = false, isGraph3Viewed = false;
    $(window).scroll(function () {
        if (isScrolledIntoView($('#myStathalf1')) && isGraph1Viewed == false) {
            $('#myStathalf1').circliful();
            isGraph1Viewed = true;
        }

        if (isScrolledIntoView($('#myStathalf2')) && isGraph2Viewed == false) {
            $('#myStathalf2').circliful();
            isGraph2Viewed = true;
        }

        if (isScrolledIntoView($('#myStathalf3')) && isGraph3Viewed == false) {
            $('#myStathalf3').circliful();
            isGraph3Viewed = true;
        }
    });

    function isScrolledIntoView(elem) {
        var docViewTop = $(window).scrollTop();
        var docViewBottom = docViewTop + $(window).height() - 10; //the 20 is the amount pixels from the bottom to consider the element in view
        var elemTop = $(elem).offset().top;
        var elemBottom = elemTop + $(elem).height();
        return ((elemBottom < docViewBottom) && (elemTop > docViewTop));
    }
});
```

This will make the code more easy to maintain, And I believe that having only 1 function bound to the scroll event might solve Your issue.

## EDIT

Another way would be to store the ID's of the elements that should get the `circliful` function called, and then join them and call only once that function:

```
$(function () {
    var isGraph1Viewed = false, isGraph2Viewed = false, isGraph3Viewed = false;
    $(window).scroll(function () {
        var circle = [];
        if (isScrolledIntoView($('#myStathalf1')) && isGraph1Viewed == false) {
            circle.push("#myStathalf1");
            isGraph1Viewed = true;
        }

        if (isScrolledIntoView($('#myStathalf2')) && isGraph2Viewed == false) {
            circle.push("#myStathalf2");
            isGraph2Viewed = true;
        }

        if (isScrolledIntoView($('#myStathalf3')) && isGraph3Viewed == false) {
            circle.push("#myStathalf3");
            isGraph3Viewed = true;
        }

        $(circle.join(',')).circliful();
    });

    function isScrolledIntoView(elem) {
        var docViewTop = $(window).scrollTop();
        var docViewBottom = docViewTop + $(window).height() - 10; //the 20 is the amount pixels from the bottom to consider the element in view
        var elemTop = $(elem).offset().top;
        var elemBottom = elemTop + $(elem).height();
        return ((elemBottom < docViewBottom) && (elemTop > docViewTop));
    }
});
```

Comment: I used your second edit, it and it seems to repeat the jquery snippet infinitely. Is there a fix to this?

Comment: edited just move the circle var declaration inside the event function

Comment: Perfect thank you so much, just out of curiosity why did the variable declaration cause so much trouble?

Comment: it had to be reset inside the event otherwise it would have the old values each time and always call circliful